# generate unique id java(not to exceed 64 bits)

Tags: java

whats a best approach to generate unique id's of long type in java, doesn't have to be a random one. went through some forums which suggested to use uuid or vmid, but they exceed 64 bit limit. any other ways of generating unique id's?

Comment: How unique do you need them to be ? Within a VM? A database? Globally?

Comment: Define a 64-bit counter and increment it every time you need a new id? Please give us some context.

Comment: i don't want to use a static variable and increment it across different classes in the application.

Comment: i have different threads running in different packages.  and I don't want to create a separate class just for declaring that static variable.

Comment: @vjk In that case can you add a static field to an existing class?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to use an AtomicLong

```
private static final AtomicLong COUNTER = new AtomicLong();
```

If you want it to be unique even after a restart you can use

```
private static final AtomicLong COUNTER = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis()*100000);
```

This produces much larger ids, but will be unique provided your clock is wound back significantly. (Daylight saving wouldn't do this)

Comment: +1 for `System.currentTimeMillis()` (nice trick), but why do you need `*100000`?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I'm guessing it's so that you can create counts in one run before running into duplicates relative to next run (plus however many millis are between runs). But then, what if you increment the counter too many times and *do* run into overlaps? If you really want values that are unique across runs, you need to persist the last count somehow.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Its to avoid the issue of overlap. '* 1` is fine if you create less than one per milli-second. `* 100000` is fine if you create less than one per 10 nano-seconds which is faster than most machine can do this and nothing else. If you are really paranoid you can use `* 10000000` and you can be sure you don't need to persist the ids because they can't be generated that fast.

Comment: @PeterLawrey can you explain in more detail the purpose of doing *100000

Comment: If you use currentTimeMillis() and you use more than one id per milli-second, when you restart, the numbers can repeat.  However if you multiple by 100000 you are fairly safe because you cannot create ids fast enough to repeat ids on a restart.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but there is simply no other (*simple*) way:

```
public enum Counter {

    INSTANCE;

    private final AtomicLong value = new AtomicLong();

    public long generate() {
        return value.incrementAndGet();
    }

}
```

And use everywhere you want:

```
Counter.INSTANCE.generate();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
java.util.UUID.randomUUID().hashCode()
```

or

```
Integer.toHexString(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().hashCode())
```

(32 bits only)